# Do single items on the Windows Start Menu need a folder?

Tags: menu, windows-os, windows-8, folders

My team is creating an application that has a single entry point. There will be a single entry point, meaning only one item on the Windows 7 start menu/Windows 8 start screen. Other than "that's how it is done", can anyone explain why users would benefit from placing this one item a folder?  I say that going directly under "All programs" makes it faster to access for users who don't search or use the desktop to start applications.

Comment: maybe there was benefit in Windows <= XP when single items would sort after the list of folders, but in 7, single items are at the top, and in 8, I think all items in a folder are displayed (grouped) anyways

Answer (score 1):

As far as I'm concerned, putting **single** entry points into folders is just annoying. However, if I have multiple program entry points and they can be categorised, I'd put them in folders. **But** that's just my preference.

To be frank: users will put things wherever the f*** they want. I know people who OCD-style categorise everything and would put your entry point in two hunderd layers of folders. I also know people who don't give two s**ts where their programs are.

The point being, as a developer **it is irrelevant** to you where users put their icons, as long as they can get at them. However, you might want to know what your users find most useful so you can install it there to start with. I can only say 'do some research' to that: every group of users is different, so talk to yours and find our what they like.

Comment: This has been an OCD of mine. I definitely prefer single entries to not have a directory. There also should not be an uninstaller in the start menu, there's a dedicated UI for uninstallers. The readme does not belong in there, either, nor do product links, etc. A good example of using a folder is Microsoft Office, a bad example is anything by Adobe.

Comment: +1 for being driven to the point of obsenity, but pulling back and going with asterisks. I feel your pain, truly.